# gnome packages won't update after upgrading to 23.10

Tags: apt, gnome, upgrade, gnome-shell, 23.10

Alright, I'm turning here after quite a bit of effort on my end, but I've run out of things to try short of reinstalling. I came across this issue after I updated to 23.10 and ran update commands. As you can see in the screenshot below, packages can be upgraded, but there are dependency errors that I'm having trouble resolving. Anything helps here. I've rebooted about 7 times, run update commands, but no dice.

Thanks in advance!

[these are the broken packages (except signal-desktop)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfRxB.png)

[return of sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade gnome-shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKEa1.png)